# Is there a function to set metadata only for a specific folder?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, folder, microsoft-teams

I have added a new column for a subfolder and grouped it afterwards. However, the main folder now also adopts this logic.

In teams this is even the case for all channels in the team.

Can I somehow apply a metadata structure only to certain folders?

Answer (score 0):

This is how SharePoint document libraries work. When you add a new column in document library, it is added at library level & not folder/subfolder level.

Similarly, if you change any library view settings (like grouping/filters/sorting), change will be applied at document library level & not folder/subfolder level.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, there is no option to only apply a metadata structure to certain folders.